# Why do we ever need to set "--aot false" in angular prod build?

Tags: angular, angular-cli-v7

I know that "`ahead of time compilation`" provides compilation at the build time. There are also bunch of other advantages of `--aot` such as

- the application is pre-compiled so there is no such a wait  template
- binding errors will be known at build time etc..

However, there is also an option to set `--aot` to false (for the prod build as well). Why do we ever need to set `--aot` to `false`? In other word, what kind of advantage does `--jit` provides? I just want to understand if there is any disadvantage of using `--aot` over `--jit` because otherwise, it sounds like I should always use `--aot` even in dev build. And if there is no trade-off by using `--aot`, then why it is not set as default for the `ng build` and `ng serve` ?

Comment: Historically, AOT is just much slower and therefore JIT was the preferred way for local development. With Angular 9 and Ivy, AOT is the default even for development builds, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Ingo Burk mentioned in the comment, I end up with same findings so I wanted to post it as an answer.

- Angular 9 actually using AOT as default now.
- AOT takes longer than JIT (so for quick testing to some little fixes, it might be useful)
- [The AOT collector only understands a subset of JavaScript. Define metadata objects with the following limited syntax](https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler#no-arrow-functions)

Also other interesting thing I found out was,

- [The AOT compiler does not support function expressions and arrow functions, also called lambda functions.](http://The%20AOT%20compiler%20does%20not%20support%20function%20expressions%20and%20arrow%20functions,%20also%20called%20lambda%20functions.)

However In version 5 and later, the compiler automatically performs this rewriting while emitting the .js file

Answer (score 0):

AOT is good in terms of performance as code is complied much before loading to the browser as in JIT.
It is now byDefault available after Angular 8.
@CuriousBOy and @Ingo mention a few use cases where Jit is preferred.

One More use case I want to add for **dynamic component and module rendering**.

If you need to create the component at runtime and want to render it you might need JIT in Browser,
*because AOT will not be able to compile the code as the Dynamic component and  Dynamic module are not available at the build time*.